# Have difficulties to align elements with boostrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have some difficulties working with some CSS/HTML properties. I'm using bootstrap to have good rendering.

So I would like to have this : 
[image]

The img is perfect but the problem is in the date (02.03.2013). I have put a float left on the img so the h3 works perfectly but not the date.

Could you help me please ? Here is what i have : http://jsbin.com/uqadoc/1/edit

Comment: What have you got so far? Can we see the html?

Comment: What I already have : http://jsbin.com/uqadoc/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

Place a div around the `<h3>` and the `<p>` ( your date )
Have the H3 with a  fixed width,  and a Float:left;
and the p,  float:right;

note : ive gone for a non div apreach in the jf but same concept

```
  <div class='main'>
    <img src='' class='ims'>
       <div class='content'>

           <h3 class="qwe" >serwqerqwrewqr</h3>



           <p class="wer">dafdf</p>
          <div class="rty" >


               sfdg
               ffffffffffffffffffffff
           fdsffffffffffff</br>


          sfdg
               ffffffffffffffffffffff
           fdsffffffffffff</br>          sfdg
               ffffffffffffffffffffff
           fdsffffffffffff</br>          sfdg
               ffffffffffffffffffffff
           fdsffffffffffff</br>
</div>
</div> 
</div>


.main{
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    background:black;
}
.content{
    width:100ps;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
}
.ims{
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:200px;
    background:blue;
}
    .qwe{
        float:left;
    width:300px
        height:50px;
    }

    .wer{

    width:200px
        height:50px;
        float:right;      
    }
 .rty{
padding-top:80px;
    width:400px
        float:right;      
    }
```

Jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/qAEzr/

Comment: use % then.  Play with this.  Please provide ''SOME'' code next time :) http://jsfiddle.net/qAEzr/

Comment: give me a mo ;) can you put this in the origenal question :D ?